# Start windows Service at multiple times

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I writing a windows c# service and I have to start my Service at different time. The times are not fixed they are dynamic and can be more than one in a day let say at time1: 11:50 am, time2: 12:50 pm, time1: 16:24 pm. My service starts correctly at the 1st time only but then it just starting randomly

this is my Code

```
  foreach (var timer in args)
        {

            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

            _timer.Enabled = true;

            _scheduleTime = Convert.ToDateTime(timer);
            _timer.Interval = _scheduleTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds * 1000;

            _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);



        }
```

Timer_Elapsed code is:

```
  protected void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //onDebug();
            Console.WriteLine("Completed Successfully");
            Log.writeFile("Completed Successfully");
            if (_timer.Interval != 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
            {
                _timer.Interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

What I want to do is start service at the time given in the array args

Thanks

Comment: It seems very odd to start and stop services like that.  How are the start times determined?

Comment: The array of args has start times in it which is iterating one by one in it

Comment: the interval of the Timer isn't very accurate, so if you want to get it more accurate.  Set the interval e.g. to 1 minute and determine (_scheduletime - datetime.now) if the service should be started or not. For schedules i can recommend the Quartz.NET library. it supports a lot of features and is very accurate. https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/